# how to send MMS from the iphone by programming?

Tags: iphone

i have implemening image sharing functionality in my application.
I have implemented email sharing functionality but i dont know MMS functionality.Please advice me how to implement MMS functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending MMS in iphone programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585439/sending-mms-in-iphone-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible with current API.

I've seen a workaround in SMS-box application: it copies text and image to clipboard and then asks user to paste it in standard sms app.

You can see it in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2gY5w1QUnY (from 2:15)