# Sending MMS in iphone programmatically

Tags: ios4

I have tried searching almost all the blog sites. I need to send an MMS programatically. As far as my research on this I came to know that its not possible for IOS < 3. Is there any way i can use the messageUI kit fot sending MMS for IOS 4.

Please let me know the possible ways.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should also look at the official documentation before searching blogs.

Comment: You can send MMS. Just please look at this answer which i had posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12739608/1443976

Answer (score 5):

You cannot send MMS right now. `MFMessageComposeViewController` only allow SMS messages on iOS 4 only.

Answer (score 0):

iOS prevents SMS or MMS messages from being sent programmatically. You can compose the message, providing the "To" and the body of the message (in iOS 4+) and display a dialog that allows the user to tap a button and send it, but user intervention is always required.

Comment: Why the downvote, mysterious person? Displeased at the accuracy or something?