# Is it possible to send an MMS from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I have searched around and cant find a solution or even a mention of it. I wondered if it is possible.

Can an MMS be sent from within an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question [Sending MMS in iphone programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585439/sending-mms-in-iphone-programmatically)

Your other option is to implement it yourself with your own custom web service.