# Send image through iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to send mms through iphone. i search a lot but failed
Please give me a good reference or link
So i can implement mms thing in my iphone or alternative thing to it
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide less detail please? This isn't quite vague enough.

Comment: i just want a good reference to study about how to send mms programmatically in iphone.

Comment: This isn't the place for recommendations and tutorials, you need Google for that. Tell us what you've tried and ask a specific question.

Comment: ok but i search a lot for that. i have no option now thats why

Comment: i am not asking for any code @Widor. i can study in my way.. problem is that i cant find a good reference.

Comment: Well I am disappointed as you said you searched a lot.. I found this many questions here on SO only..[For the current iphone version, MMS is possible or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028542/for-the-current-iphone-version-mms-is-possible-or-not)[Sending MMS programatically in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576253/sending-mms-programatically-in-iphone)[how to send MMS from the iphone by programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594253/how-to-send-mms-from-the-iphone-by-programming)

Comment: If you don't believe the answers you find, there's not a lot we can do to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iOS SDK does not support sending MMS, only SMS.

See the documentation on [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for information about sending a SMS.

There may be are third party service that will allow you to send MMS, but they will probably charge you per MMS.